# Проблема повторное подключение с++

Tags: c++, ооп, файлы, архитектура

***Помогите***

Не понимаю в чем ошибка

Вроде защиту от повторного подключения поставил, но выдаёт ошибку

> console_stl_out.h

```
#ifndef _CONSOLE_STL_OUT_H
#define _CONSOLE_STL_OUT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

template<class x>
void show(x a);

template<class x>
void show(std::queue<x> a);

template<class x>
void show(std::vector<std::vector<x>> a);

#endif
```

> console_stl_out.cpp

```
#include "console_stl_out.h"

template<class x>
void show(x a) {
    for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); i++) {
        std::cout << *i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
template<class x>
void show(std::queue<x> a) {
    while (!a.empty()) {
        std::cout << a.front() << " ";
        a.pop();
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

template<class x>
void show(std::vector<std::vector<x>> a) {
    for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); i++) {
        show(*i);
    }
}
```

> Source.cpp

```
  #include <iostream>


#include "console_stl_out.h"

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));


    vector<int> a = { 1,2,12,12,1,2 };
    show(a);


    cout << endl;
    system("pause>null");
}
```

Хотя единым монолитом работает!

> Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

//#include "console_stl_out.h"

using namespace std;

template<class x>
void show(x a);

template<class x>
void show(std::queue<x> a);

template<class x>
void show(std::vector<std::vector<x>> a);
template<class x>
void show(x a) {
    for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); i++) {
        std::cout << *i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
template<class x>
void show(std::queue<x> a) {
    while (!a.empty()) {
        std::cout << a.front() << " ";
        a.pop();
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

template<class x>
void show(std::vector<std::vector<x>> a) {
    for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); i++) {
        show(*i);
    }
    }

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));


    vector<int> a = { 1,2,12,12,1,2 };
    show(a);


    cout << endl;
    system("pause>null");
}
```

1>C:\Users\Nikita\source\repos\LearnC++\LearnC++\Source.cpp(12,15): warning C4244: аргумент: преобразование "time_t" в "unsigned int", возможна потеря данных
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl show<class std::vector<int,class std::allocator > >(class std::vector<int,class std::allocator >)" (??$show@V?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@@YAXV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z) в функции main.
1>C:\Users\Nikita\source\repos\LearnC++\x64\Debug\LearnC++.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1

Comment: И где же ты увидел повторное подключение?

Comment: не по теме. обьясните мне, зачем писать такую конструкцию, если есть pragma once, которую все компиляторы хавают?

Comment: Если ты в хедере реализацию шаблонов напишешь, то все заработает, ты обьявил шаблон в хедере, а реализацию в цпп сделал, напиши реализацию в хедере и будет счасьте

Comment: Как сказал @Aptem_f шаблонные функции и методы не могут быть реализованы отдельно от интерфейса класса, их реализация также пишется внутри .h файла. Ошибка вам об этом и сообщает. Если бы у вас было повторное подключение, то вам бы выбило ошибку о повторном определении функций/классов и т.д.